# SQL Error:Column Index Out of Range,2>1

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I want to throw notification of any upcoming cases in a law cases monitoring system. Here is my code-

```
try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        cn22= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mmtc?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "");
        st22=cn22.createStatement();
        st23=cn22.createStatement();
        st24=cn22.createStatement();
        st25=cn22.createStatement();


    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Connected.");

    }
    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yy");
    Date dateobj=new Date();
    String datetoday=df.format(dateobj);

    Date todaydate=datechanger(datetoday);
    DateTime dt1=new DateTime(todaydate);
    String fetchdate="Select nextdate from newentry where location='"+Login.locationofcurrentuser+"'";
    String fetchdatecount="select count(*) as total from newentry where location='"+Login.locationofcurrentuser+"'";
    ResultSet rsdash=st23.executeQuery(fetchdate);
    ResultSet rsdashcount=st24.executeQuery(fetchdatecount);
    String dategetter="Select caseno from newentry where location='"+Login.locationofcurrentuser+"'";
             ResultSet rss786=st25.executeQuery(dategetter);

    if(rsdashcount.next()){

      int size=rsdashcount.getInt("total");


    ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> caseno=new ArrayList<String>();
     while(rss786.next()){
         int y=1;
         while(y<=size){
             caseno.add(rss786.getString(y++));

         }
     }


      ArrayList<Date> dates=new ArrayList<Date>();
      while(rsdash.next()){
          int z=1;
          while(z<=size){
              a.add(rsdash.getString(z++));
          }
      }


     for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
         dates.add(datechanger(a.get(i)));



         DateTime dt2=new DateTime(dates.get(i));
         int gap=Days.daysBetween(dt1,dt2).getDays();
         ArrayList<String> b=new ArrayList<String>();

         if (gap<4){



               b.add("Upcoming case-"+caseno.get(i)+" due on-"+a.get(i)+""); 
               System.out.println(b);








         }
         notification.setText(b.toString());


     }


    }else
    {
        notification.setText("No Upcoming Cases.");
    }
```

If I have one entry in my newentry table it works fine and throws notification in my dashboard as well.
As soon as I make a second entry in the table it throws an sql error-

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 2 > 1. 
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkColumnBounds(ResultSetImpl.java:831)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5774)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5693)
at mmtc.Dashboard.<init>(Dashboard.java:79)
```

The line 79 of my code is-

```
 caseno.add(rss786.getString(y++));
```

This is my first project and I am learning. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have `rss786.getString(y++)` and  `rsdash.getString(z++)` instead you can have `rss786.getString(1)` and `rsdash.getString(1)` since your corresponding queries have only one column for your resultSet.

When you enter second row in table, the while loop before line 79 iterates twice and tries to get `rss786.getString(2)` - which means fetch column 2 from query that does not exist, hence 'Column Index out of range, 2 > 1'.

Hope that you're clear with the usage now!

Comment: Works perfect now. Thanks :)